# TextField ellipsis nativescript

Tags: android, nativescript

I'm developing a Nativescript app, and in some devices the hint is bigger than the input, IOS add three dots at the end (...) like an ellipsis, but android only cut off the hint.
I tried the following code:

```
let shareInput: TextField = this.page.getViewById<TextField>('share-input');
shareInput.android.setEllipsize("end");
```

I'm getting an error like this:

> java.lang.Exception: Failed resolving method setEllipsize on class
>   android.widget.EditText

I red some android issues and tried to use setSingleLine method but it does not work.

Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this method is what you need (and are using :) - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#setEllipsize(android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt)

your argument is incorrect, it isn't expecting a string but an ENUM.
So try `setEllipsize(android.text.TextUtils.TruncateAt.END)`

And if you're going to be setting this on multiple fields I would add a var for the `TruncateAt` enum like `const TruncateAt = android.test.TextUtils.TruncaeAT` then just use that const/var in the argument like `(TruncateAt.END)` to save on repeating yourself.